# how to convert 4d numpy array to PIL image?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm doing some image machine learning by keras and if i put one picture converted to numpy.array in my model, it returns a 4d numpy array(predicted picture).

I want to convert that array to image by using Image.fromarray in PIL library.
but Image.fromarray only accept 2d array or 3d array.

my predicted picture's array shape is (1, 256, 256, 3) 1 means number of data.
so 1 is useless data for image. I want to convert it to(256,256,3) with not damaging image data. what should I do? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `arr[0,:,:,:]` removes that first dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj better style would be to use numpy.squeeze

Comment: @Finomnis, I don't see why it's any better.

Comment: @hpaulj because it checks whether the first dimension is actually empty. Your code would just ignore additional images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is not useless data, it is a singular dimension. You can just leave it out, the size of the data wouldn't change.

You can do that with [numpy.squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html).

Also, make sure that your data is in the right format, for Image.fromarray this is uint8.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

data = np.ones((1,16,16,3))
for i in range(16):
    data[0,i,i,1] = 0.0

print("size: %s, type: %s"%(data.shape, data.dtype))
# size: (1, 16, 16, 3), type: float64

data_img = (data.squeeze()*255).astype(np.uint8)

print("size: %s, type: %s"%(data_img.shape, data_img.dtype))
# size: (16, 16, 3), type: uint8

img = Image.fromarray(data_img, mode='RGB')
img.show()
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I got the image file but there's some problem.. 
image shows black(when i print it's array, array is all 0)

if i erase '.astype(np.uint8)', image shows something but still weird. (but i don't know if it's because  my model doesn't work properly or code is something wrong) do you have any idea about this? thank you.

Comment: Did you add the *255? Some neural networks output values between 0.0 and 1.0, which round to uint8(0). Some neural networks even have a different normalization function for images, you have to find out and de-normalize properly.